# How can I add the current directory to the search path in UNIX?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal

I cannot fix the command not found errors in UNIX bash.
I need to add the current directory to my search path. However, I searched in google but I cannot find anything which tells me the direct solution (since I am in the beginner level and it is hard to understand)

when I write to terminal `pwd`, it says

```
/Users/macbook
```

when I write `echo $PATH`, it says

```
/Users/macbook/opt/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/macbook/OPT/BIN:/Users/macbook/opt/bin
```

How can I add the current directory to my search path?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: is your question about adding current path to $PATH?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this in your terminal, it should work.

```
PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)
```

Comment: @AndréDaniel I am doing that. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want bash to always search the current directory first for the command, not matter in which directory you are currently in, you can add "." to your PATH variable. For that, edit the file `.bash_profile` or `.profile` file in your home directory (first one present) and add the line:

```
PATH=.:$PATH
```

Comment: However, as any Unix FAQ will tell you, this is insecure, and thus in violation of recommended practice.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it does have security issues. Probably putting the dot at the end of the PATH is less insecure.

Comment: No, not significantly. The fundamental problem remains; if the current directory is writable by others, they can plant something there for you to execute. They won't be able to override system commands, so the attack surface is smaller, but catching a common typo (say, `sl` for `ls`) will still work.